# How to "stop" BFS algorithm in certain step C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breadth-first-search

I'm currently developing a board game called Trivial Persuit for 2-4 players. The main objetive is to roll a dice and move in the board the steps the dice show to them.
The board its a hexagon with edges inside aswell (a lot of possible ways for the player to choose)

It's all going great until the this moment that I need to apply the BFS alghorithm. I implemented the graph and the BFS just fine but now I cannot rectrict the search for certain steps/distances.

I believe that I need to create a variable distance or something like that but I can't figure out  how to do it... Could you guys help me out?

Cheers guys!

This is my BFS code:

```
public HashSet<T> BFS<T>(Graph<T> graph, T start, Action<T> preVisit = null)
{    
    var visited = new HashSet<T>();

    if (!graph.AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(start))
        return visited;

    var queue = new Queue<T>();
    queue.Enqueue(start);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var vertex = queue.Dequeue();

        if (visited.Contains(vertex))
            continue;

        if (preVisit != null)
            preVisit(vertex);

        visited.Add(vertex);

        foreach (var neighbor in graph.AdjacencyList[vertex])
            if (!visited.Contains(neighbor))
                queue.Enqueue(neighbor);
    }

    return visited;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you question, about how to limit the BFS algorithm when a certain depth/level is reached, you could keep track of the depth of each node and just stop the algorithm when there is no more nodes in your desired level of depth.
Here is a snippet using a Tuple based on your code:

```
public HashSet<T> BFS<T>(Graph<T> graph, T start, int maxDepth, Action<T> preVisit = null)
{
    var visited = new HashSet<T>();

    if (!graph.AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(start))
        return visited;

    var queue = new Queue<Tuple<T, int>>();
    // Consider the start is in the depth "0"
    queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<T, int>(start, 0)); 

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        Tuple<T, int> vertexWithDepth = queue.Dequeue();
        var vertex = vertexWithDepth.Item1;

        if (visited.Contains(vertex))
            continue;

        if (preVisit != null)
            preVisit(vertex);

        visited.Add(vertex);

        // If the current vertex's level is greater or equals
        // the maximum desired level, skip adding its
        // adjacent vertexes.
        int vertexLevel = vertexWithDepth.Item2;
        if(vertexLevel >= maxDepth)
             continue;

        foreach (var neighbor in graph.AdjacencyList[vertex])
            if (!visited.Contains(neighbor))
                queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<T, int>(neighbor, vertexLevel + 1));
    }

    return visited;
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: That's it, thanks! By the way if, for example, the maxDepth = 2 how can I obtain only the depth = 2 vertex's not showing the depth 0 and 1 vertex's?

Comment: You could have an extra collection where you store your "result". You could add vertices to this collection only if they have the desired path. So after `visited.Add(...)` you do: `if( vertexWithDepth.Item2 == desiredPath) result.Add(vertex);`, then you return the `result`.  Another solution would be to simply change your `visited` HashSet to a custom class that holds the vertex and its depth (replacing the Tuple), then you could return all the visited vertex with their depth and simply *filter* from the calling code: `var r = BFS(/* ... */).Where(v => v.Depth == 2).Select(v => v.Vertex)`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be done simpler based on your need:
You might not need the second check in the while loop, but it won't hurt.

```
public HashSet<T> BFS<T>(Graph<T> graph, T start, int maxSteps, Action<T> preVisit = null)
{    
var visited = new HashSet<T>();

if (!graph.AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(start))
    return visited;

int stepsTaken = 0;
var queue = new Queue<T>();
queue.Enqueue(start);

while (queue.Count > 0 && stepsTaken < maxSteps)
{
    var vertex = queue.Dequeue();

    if (visited.Contains(vertex))
        continue;

    if (preVisit != null)
        preVisit(vertex);

    visited.Add(vertex);

    foreach (var neighbor in graph.AdjacencyList[vertex])
    {
        stepsTaken++;
        if (!visited.Contains(neighbor) && stepsTaken < maxSteps)
            queue.Enqueue(neighbor);
    }

return visited;
}
```